# Will_paginate flush additional query params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Here's a problem. I have a pretty simple forum app and a `TopicsController#show` action that renders a topic page with the posts on it. The posts are rendered using `will_paginate gem`.
But the action also allows you to go to a specific post instead of a specific page (e.g. `/topics/23?post=235`) and it automatically calculates the page you should be on, and it works fine.

Except that the `will_paginate` helper generates links persisting that `post` parameter in them so even if you click that link, you'll get back to the same page, 'cause the `post` parameter is present.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the params you want will_paginate to use. Usually you want them all so in this case you want to remove the one you don't want. A little ugly, but it works:

```
= will_paginate @topics, params: params.reject{|k,v| k == 'post'}
```

You could wrap that up in a helper to clean things up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails, you can do this even more tersely:

```
= will_paginate @topics, params: params.except('post')
```

http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except